# Need to Scrape Paginated Pages in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a selenium / python script that scrapes page titles and some other information. At the bottom of the page is a "next" button along with some pagination that loads the next 20 results or so when I click next. This all happens without a page load. I need to be able to scrape the remaining pages until the "next" button is no longer visible, which indicates there are no more results to be loaded. Below is the logic I have so far to give you an idea. I have simplified it so it's easily followed. I can scrape the first page of titles, but once the browser clicks "next" the script terminates. How do I get it to scrape the remaining pages? Thanks!

```
#loads web page
browser.get("URL")

#scrapes titles
deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("element xpath")
titles = []
    for title in deal_title:
    titles.append(title.text)

#clicks next button
browser.find_element_by_xpath("button xpath")

print(title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop to repeat the process. This should work. And you might want to put sufficient sleep or waits to make sure all elements on the page gets loaded. Also may be try not to use Xpath as much. If you can target class or id that would be better.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:


      title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("element xpath")
      titles = []
      for title in deal_title:
         titles.append(title.text)

      try:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath of the next button").click()


      except NoSuchElementExeception :
             break
```

Comment: There is no such operator as `catch` in Python. `deal_title` is not defined in your code. There are several obvious problems with indentation in your code. Also you need to import `NoSuchElementExeception ` before using it

Comment: Oops my mistake was working in java quite a while catch came automatically instead of except. Regarding import i think its understood.Anyway made the changes